# CSS for Media (755.4px - 991.4px)

Tags: css, responsive

Is it possible to write CSS for that affects a screen only when width is 755.4px - 991.4px?

I've tried the below but it also affects anything larger then `@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 768px)`

```
@media  (min-width: 755.4px) and (max-width: 991.4px)
   #sliderText{
        top:90px !important;
        width: 85% !important;

    }

    #sliderText h1{
        font-size: 1em !important;
    }

}
```

The problem is, when the text is on a screen with width 755.4px - 991.4px, it goes on 2 lines and then it breaks the layout.

My original code is:

```
#ajax-content-wrap{
    position:relative;
}

#sliderText{
    position:absolute;
    top:85%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:50px;
    width:93%;
    z-index:100;
}

#sliderText h1{
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #31a6c7;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333;
}



@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 768px) {
   #sliderText{
        top:90px !important;
        width: 85% !important;

    }

    #sliderText h1{
        font-size: 2em !important;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
   #sliderText{
        top: 84% !important;
        width:75% !important;
        //padding-left:50px;
        //padding-right:50px;
    }

    #sliderText h1{
        font-size: 1.7em !important;
    }

}
```

Comment: The rules you show are weird. `@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 768px)` is only 2 pixels. I can't tell if this is intentional or not because you mention it in two places but also say `@media (min-width: 755.4px) and (max-width: 991.4px)` which makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to do the following

- Anything **below** `755.3px` is small `CSS`
- Anything **above** `991.4px` is big `CSS`
- Anything in the middle of that range is medium `CSS`

Here's a *simplification* of what that would look like:

```css
/* Big CSS: Applies to everything unless overwritten */

#sliderText {
  top: ;
  width:
}
#sliderText h1 {
  font-size:
}
/* Small CSS: Applies to small devices */

@media (max-width: 755.3px) {
  #sliderText {
    top: ;
    width:
  }
  #sliderText h1 {
    font-size:
  }
}
/* Middle CSS: Applies to Devices in the middle of the range above */

@media (max-width: 991.4px) {
  #sliderText {
    top: ;
    width:
  }
  #sliderText h1 {
    font-size:
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks!
How about if I wanted a range between middle and small.
For example, for devices such as:

iPhone 6 Plump landscape · width: 736px and Android (Nexus 4) landscape · width: 600px?